# How to show only user specific data in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

I am developing a Laravel application with multi auth. something similar to a multi-vendor.

I need to show data that only belong to the logged-in user. for example in the system, I have a user role "Owner". The owner is having one or many houses. and the house will have one or many rooms. a room has one or many furniture. as we have multiple owners in the system, once a Owner is logged into the system, I need to show only his house,rooms, and furnitures that belongs to him.

I have CRUD operations to each house,rooms,furnitures,owners. these operations should work too with based on logged in Owner.

what approach should I follow for this problem.  I am new with this type of filters and if anyone can support me on this it would be great thank you.

Comment: try this for getting the logged in user: `$user = \Auth::guard('web')->user();`

Comment: in my opinion is better to have each type of users in separate table in database, i mean admin users in `admins` table, owner user in `owners` table and etc.   and you can create `middleware` and `routeMiddleware` for every type of them in `App\Http\Kernel`.!

Comment: is it `spatie/laravel-permission` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

Database Schema tables (with respective ids):

```
users
roles
role_user
houses
house_user
rooms
house_room
```

Define the model relationships (example is for the users.php model)

```
public function role()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}

public function houses()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\House');
}
```

house.php model

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

etc...

Controllers:

```
function view_current_users_houses() {
  // Get all houses with current logged in user
  // find(auth()->user()->id);
  $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

  return view('view', compact('user'));
}
```

View Blade:

```
@foreach($user->houses as $houses)
  {{$house->name}}
@endforeach
```